# systemfit 3SLS Testing for Overidentification Restrictions

Tags: system, panel, equation

currently I'm struggling to find a good way to perform the Hansen/Sargan tests of Overidentification restrictions within a Three-Stage Least Squares model (3SLS) in panel data using R. I was digging the whole day in different networks and couldn't find a way of depicting the tests in R using the well-known systemfit package.

Currently, my code is simple.

```
    
violence_c_3sls <- Crime ~ ln_GDP +I(ln_GDP^2) + ln_Gini 
income_c_3sls  <-ln_GDP  ~ Crime + ln_Gini 
gini_c_3sls <- ln_Gini ~ ln_GDP + I(ln_GDP^2) + Crime 

inst <- ~ Educ_Gvmnt_Exp + I(Educ_Gvmnt_Exp^2)+ Health_Exp + Pov_Head_Count_1.9 

system_c_3sls <- list(violence_c_3sls, income_c_3sls, gini_c_3sls)

fitsur_c_3sls <-systemfit(system_c_3sls, "3SLS",inst=inst, data=df_new, methodResidCov = "noDfCor" )
summary(fitsur_c_3sls)
```

However, adding more instruments to create an over-identified system do not yield in an output of the Hansen/Sargan test, thus I assume the test should be executed aside from the output and probably associated to systemfit class object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `g` equations, `l` exogenous variables, and `k` regressors, the Sargan test for 3SLS is[image: Sargan test]

where `u` is the stacked residuals, `\Sigma` is the estimated residual covariance, and `P_W` is the projection matrix on the exogenous variables. See Ch 12.4 from [Davidson & MacKinnon ETM](http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/ETM/ETM-davidson-mackinnon-2021.pdf).

Calculating the Sargan test from systemfit should look something like this:

```
sargan.systemfit=function(results3sls){
  result <- list()

  u=as.matrix(resid(results3sls)) #model residuals, n x n_eq
  n_eq=length(results3sls$eq) # number of equations
  n=nrow(u) #number of observations
  n_reg=length(coef(results3sls)) # total number of regressors
  
  w=model.matrix(results3sls,which='z') #Matrix of instruments, in block diagonal form with one block per equation
  
  #Need to aggregate into a single block (in case different instruments used per equation)
  w_list=lapply(X = 1:n_eq,FUN = function(eq_i){
    this_eq_label=results3sls$eq[[eq_i]]$eqnLabel
    this_w=w[str_detect(rownames(w),this_eq_label),str_detect(colnames(w),this_eq_label)]
    colnames(this_w)=str_remove(colnames(this_w),paste0(this_eq_label,'_'))
    return(this_w)
  })
  w=do.call(cbind,w_list)
  w=w[,!duplicated(colnames(w))]
  n_inst=ncol(w) #w is n x n_inst, where n_inst is the number of unique instruments/exogenous variables
  
  #estimate residual variance (or use residCov, should be asymptotically equivalent)
  var_u=crossprod(u)/n #var_u=results3sls$residCov
  
  P_w=w%*%solve(crossprod(w))%*%t(w) #Projection matrix on instruments w
  

  #as.numeric(u) vectorizes the residuals into a n_eq*n x 1 vector.
  
  result$statistic <- as.numeric(t(as.numeric(u))%*%kronecker(solve(var_u),P_w)%*%as.numeric(u))

  result$df <- n_inst*n_eq-n_reg
  
  result$p.value <- 1 - pchisq(result$statistic, result$df)
  result$method = paste("Sargan over-identifying restrictions test")

  return(result)
  
  
}
```

Comment: that was exactly the answer that I was looking, thanks a lot!

Comment: Np. I just found this, if you have Stata it’d probably be a good idea to double check against it. Please let me know if you do. https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-02/msg00345.html